# Convert very long Double to String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, double, nsnumberformatter

I want to convert this number 12345678901234567000.0 to String so I had written below extension.

```swift
extension Double {
    var clean: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16
        let cleanedString = String(formatter.string(from: number) ?? "")
        if let firstLetter = cleanedString.first, firstLetter == "." {
            return "0\(cleanedString)"
        }
        return cleanedString
    }
}


let number = 12345678901234567000.0
print(number.clean) // output is 12345678901234600000
```

But it returns wrong number 12345678901234600000, 7 is gone and 2 more zeros are added.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the imprecision of `Double`. If you use `Decimal`, you don't run into this issue.

You also don't need that workaround to add a leading `0`, you should simply set `minimumIntegerDigits` to 1. You also don't need the conversion to `NSNumber`, `NumberFormatter` has a method `string(for:)` which accepts `Swift` numeric types (`Double` or `Decimal` for instance).

```
extension Decimal {
    static let cleanFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        return formatter
    }()

    var clean: String {
        let cleanedString = Decimal.cleanFormatter.string(for: self) ?? ""
        return cleanedString
    }
}

let decimalNum = Decimal(string: "12345678901234567000.0")!
decimalNum.clean // "12345678901234567000"
decimalNum.clean == "12345678901234567000" // true
```

Comment: This will create a new number formatter every time you call this property. Btw  `string(for:)` it is not an instance method of the NumberFormatter class. It is an instance method of the Formatter abstract class. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter/1415993-string

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I've only fixed what was necessary. Updated my answer with a `static` `NumberFormatter`.